# How to insert multiple values to single key in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I have an object array `var codropsEvents={[date1]:['event1'],[date2]:['event2'};`
I want to insert multiple values to event1 i.e {[date1]:['event1','event2'],..}
I use the following code

```
<?php 
    $da=[];
    $qry="select * from events";
    $ex=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex))
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime($row['date']);
        $date= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);
        $event=$row['event'];
        $da[]=$date;

        $eve[]=$event;


    }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a=<?php echo(json_encode($da)); ?>;
        var ev=  <?php echo(json_encode($eve)); ?>;
        var codropsEvents ={};
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {

            codropsEvents[a[i]] = '<span>'+[ev[i]]+'</span>';

        }

        </script>
```

But using this code I got something like this,

```
var codropsEvents={[date1]:[event1],[date1]:[event2]}
```

But I need all events with same date in a single key is `{[date1]:['event1','event2',..],[date2]:[''event3','event4'..],..};`

Please anyone can help me

Comment: `var events = <?php echo json_encode($events); ?>;`?  Whatever your original structure is, you can JSON-encode that and assign it to the variable directly.  If that's not what you want, it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Brad is saying it looks like your data structure is controlled by your PHP. So the obvious solution would be to  modify the PHP, which unfortunately you haven't shown us.

Comment: I edited the code in the question. Please check it and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the **key** exists in the object, if not initialize it with empty array. Then push elements into the array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=<?php echo(json_encode($da)); ?>;
    var ev=  <?php echo(json_encode($eve)); ?>;
    var codropsEvents ={};
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {

        if (!codropsEvents[a[i]]) {
            codropsEvents[a[i]] = [];
        }
        codropsEvents[a[i]].push('<span>'+[ev[i]]+'</span>');

    }

</script>
```